# How to update the values of an index column in a free table?

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am supporting a legacy application written in Visual FoxPro 9, and I need some guidance in how to modify the values in an index column of a free table.

The table definition is as follows:
[image: Table Definition]

I want to increment the value of the "lrecordno" column by 1,000 IF the "nversion" column contains a specific value (for example, "22.30").

What is the proper sequence of steps to accomplish this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working in Visual FoxPro using SQL:

```
USE tableName SHARED
UPDATE tableName SET lrecordno = lrecordno + 1000 WHERE nversion = 22.30
USE
```

Or using the FoxPro `REPLACE` command:

```
USE tableName SHARED
REPLACE lrecordno WITH lrecordno + 1000 FOR nversion = 22.30
USE
```

These will affect all records that match the `WHERE` or `FOR` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

You don't show enough information to indicate whether what you want to do is safe. If iRecordNo is the primary key or a candidate key for the table, then modifying its values programmatically can lead to errors.

So, what kind of an index does that field have? If it is primary or candidate, how does it get its values in the first place? From the figure you show, it's not AutoIncrementing.

Tamar

Comment: Tamar, Thank you for the followup.  How can I get the information you are requesting out of FoxPro?

Comment: In the dialog you showed, click on the Indexes tab and you'll be able to see what kind of index you have. As for where the values come from, based on what you've shown, they're either user-supplied or generated in the application's code; to figure out which, you'll have to look at the form where these things are added.

Comment: Okay, that's a regular index, so it won't stop you from have repeats. So, what you want to do should work.

Comment: Great!  Last followup:  After the update statement executes, will the next row inserted into the table use the next available value for that column?

Comment: No. If you want that, you have to make the field Integer (AutoInc) and then set the NextValue property to the one you want. You could use ALTER TABLE to do that after you finish your changes.